# Updated code for MagTek's encrypted card reader?

Tags: vb.net

I am currently writing a function that needs to read encrypted card data from a Magtek reader and send it to their WS to be decrypted. I download the source code for the reader from the website and it runs fine on VB6, however I need to get this onto Visual Studio 2010. This here is the code from the VB6 version:

```
 If nValueNameLen > 0 Then

          ReDim Preserve Values(0 To 1, 0 To nStrings) As String
          Values(0, nStrings) = Left$(ValueName, nValueNameLen)
          Values(1, nStrings) = Left$(Value, nValueLen - 1)
          nStrings = nStrings + 1

 End If
```

When I run it in 2005 or 2010 to update it, the code looks like this:

```
 If nValueNameLen > 0 Then

          ReDim Preserve Values(1, nStrings)
          Values(0, nStrings) = Left(ValueName, nValueNameLen)
          Values(1, nStrings) = Left(Value, nValueLen - 1)
          nStrings = nStrings + 1

 End If
```

This causes a "'ReDim' cannot change the number of dimensions of an array" error, amongst the plethora of other errors that results when trying to update. Is there a fix I can do for this or any more current code one can use if they're trying to implement the card reader into their own program (In VB.net of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values was probably declared like:

```
Dim Values() as String
```

when it needs to be declared:

```
Dim Values(,) as String
```